# Why crystal report not refresh the parameters automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I am using this code in asp.net to run crystal report :

```
paramField.Name = "@ORDER_ID";
                        paramDiscreteValue.Value = TXTORDERID.Text.ToString();
                        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                        paramFields.Add(paramField);

                        paramField = new ParameterField(); // <-- This line is added
                        paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();  // <-- This line is added
                        paramField.Name = "@branch_id";

                        paramDiscreteValue1.Value = TXTDEPTID.Text.ToString();
                        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue1);
                        paramFields.Add(paramField);

                        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh = false;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
                        reportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/RPT/RPTCCOVIDRESULTS.rpt"));

                       
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

when I remove this line of code its run always same report automatically :

```
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

when I add this line its ask always for parameters .

How to referesh the report automatically and run the report without asking each time for order and branch id , I confused about it and I need your help please .
see image and thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this code

```
repDocument.SetParameterValue("@ORDER_ID", TXTORDERID.Text);
```

instead of parameter fields this is complete solution and works with me

```
                        var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                        connectionInfo.ServerName =   "server_name";
                        connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "database_name";
                        connectionInfo.Password = "password";
                        connectionInfo.UserID = "user_name";
                        connectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL;
                        connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                        ReportDocument repDocument = new ReportDocument();
                        repDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/report.rpt"));
                        repDocument.SetParameterValue("@ORDER_ID", TXTORDERID.Text);
                        repDocument.SetParameterValue("@branch_id", TXTBRANCHID.Text);

                        repDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("user_name", "password");
                        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = repDocument;
                        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
                        for (int i = 0; i < CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Count; i++)
                        {
                            CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo[i].ConnectionInfo = connectionInfo;
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you its working with this solution

Answer (score 0):

try to use the api viewer core ;)

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ViewerCore.ReuseParameterWhenRefresh = true;
```

Before invoke RefreshReport() method, then

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

it works for me in WPF